# Why is there a semi-colon in the object structure for expected props in this typescript react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Check out this example code I saw:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const Count: React.FunctionComponent<{
  count: number; // this is the line that confuses me
}> = (props) => {
  return <h1>{props.count}</h1>;
};

export default Count;
```

That object structure is defining expected props, but since when is it syntactically correct to have semi-colons after k-v pairs in an object? This must be a Typescript syntax I'm unfamiliar with, but I'm not sure what it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the equivalent of defining an interface, just without a name, so is following the syntax [shown here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

```js
interface CountInterface {
    count: number;
}
```

It's not actually a key-value pair, it's more a key-type pair. Due to the way typescript needs to work, this means that it is a set of statements (ending in semi-colon), and although it looks like an object literal, it's not.

So, yes, it is a "typescript thing", which allows for type-checking to take place.